# Mounting nfs shares that are already mounted on host, inside docker container

Tags: bash, docker, containers, mount, nfs

I have a mounted nfs share on my host server with ro privileges only:

fstab:

```
<xxxxxxx>:/export  /data   nfs     ro,proto=tcp,hard,noauto,x-systemd.automount,x-systemd.idle-timeout=600 0       0
```

I want to mount this /data directory on the host to the docker container using the following command:

```
docker run -it --rm -v /data:/data ubuntu
```

Unfortunately, when I enter the container and run cd /data I get: bash: cd: /data/: Permission denied

Worth mentioning that the contents of /data folder and visible on host. I am also aware that I can mount an NFS share directly to the docker container but I would like to avoid that.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Note that NFS permissions rely on UIDs. What is the UID of the user (inside the docker container) doing the `cd /data`? Does this UID have permission to access the NFS share?

Comment: Inside the container "echo $UID" returns id 0. On the host ls -la reveals 
drwx------  40 root root    43 Apr  5 13:29 data
and the root's uid is 0 as well.

Comment: I think it's pretty common for NFS servers to treat a user ID of 0 as "nobody" ("squash root").